# Detecting established VPN when iDevice is using 3G/UMTS/Edge

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, vpn

if the iDevice is connected to the internet via WiFi I'm able to detect VPN-status using `kSCNetworkFlagsTransientConnection`. It works fine.

But in the case of 3G/UMTS this flag is always true.

VPN on/off is both `Reachability Flag Status: WR t----l-` .

Is there a way to detect the VPN-status when the iDevice is connected to the internet via 3G/UMTS/EDGE ... ?

Comment: Did you find a way? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: No satisfying solution found. In the case of mobile-net I just used the reachability API to let the user know when the server is not reachable and asked then to make sure that vpn is enabled on the device.

Answer (score 3):

In case this is still of value. I found a way to test. At least for IPSec and Juniper it appears that the VPN connection alters the device's proxy settings:

```
NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
```

When VPN is not on, dict has 0 items. When VPN is on, dict has a content relevant to the particular vpn connection.

Comment: Clearly, if using ARC, you might want to use `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease`.

Comment: BTW, I tested this and I see no entries when on cellular but have entries when on a standard home wifi network (but not a VPN). Or, for the purposes of this question, are you considering a wifi network to be a VPN?

Comment: You should look for `ppp0` and `utun0` keys inside `__SCOPED__` in said dictionary. The presence of these keys indicates a connected VPN.